# probability on projectile, serial incident and geometry.

Tags: probability

> (i)  A bullet is fired at an angle $60^{\circ}$ from the ground with a velocity $300ms^{-1}$ . What is the probability of finding the bullet at a height of $20$ m or more when checked at any time after shooting . [$g=10 ms^{-1}$]  ?

**MY WORK:**

I find the maximum height $H=\frac{(30\sin 60^{\circ})^2}{2g}=33.75$ . So,  the probability I get :
$$\frac{2\times (33.75-20)}{33.75}$$
$$=\frac{22}{27}$$

> (ii) There are $5$ red and $2$ white marbles. If a marble is drawn without replacement,  what is the probability of the last one to be red?

**MY WORK:**

I actually did not understand what it meant.  I assumed that *a marble* is drawn every time and at last the marble should be red.  So,  I get :
$$\frac{2}{7}\times \frac{1}{6}\times \frac{5}{5}\times ...\frac{1}{1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{21}$$

> (iii) $6$ points are drawn in a circle.  What is the probability of the points to be in the same semi circle?

**MY WORK:**

I did it usually, like the probability of finding a single point is equal to the probability of finding the rest. So I did :

$$\frac{\text{Area of semi circle }}{\text{Area of whole circle }}$$
$$=\frac{1}{4}$$

**AM I CORRECT ?**

Comment: For the first one, the model makes that there is uniform probability on TIME, not HEIGHT. So you have to divide the duration the bullet is above 20m by the total duration of the flight of the bullet.

Comment: One the second one, you have to consider all the possible orders of drawing seven marbles one by one, and count the number of drawings where the last one is red.

Comment: ON the third one, the points are on a CIRCLE, not on a DISC.

Comment: @Nicolas...  I understood the first one...  But the second and third one is not understandable...

Comment: Simple way to solve the second : there are 7 marbles, 2 are red, so the probability that the last drawn ball is red is $\frac27$ :-)

Comment: But you are not sure there is uniformity on the last drawn marble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (ii) : suppose the marbles are numbered from 1 to 7, and that marbles 6 and 7 are white. A drawing is a permutation of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, there are $7!$ different orders, and all orders are equal (so there is a uniform probability on the set of outcomes).

There are $6!$ orders where the last marble is the number $1$, and the same $6!$ orders for which the last marble is one of the numbers $2$ to $5$. So the total number of drawings for which the last marble is red is $5\times6!$.

Therefore the probability you're looking for is 
$$\frac{5\times6!}{7!} = \frac{5}{7}$$

Comment: There are $5$ red balls  ...

Comment: @Entrepreneur : oups, sorry, correction done.